# Windows PC as a Router ? (Without ICS)

Tags: windows, router, internet, ipv4

My PC (running Windows 10 Pro) has two interfaces:

LAN 1: 10.1.0.100/16 , Default Gateway : 10.1.0.1
LAN 2: 192.168.100.1/24

I also have another PC connected to the second LAN interface with IP 192.168.100.2/24.

I have enabled IP Packet Forwarding (IPEnableRouter=1). However I can ping only 10.1.0.100 from PC. I cannot even ping the higher up router @ 10.1.0.1, and obviously the internet does not work.

What more do I need to do to set the proper routes and gateways for the second interface ?

Comment: Does the "higher up router" have a route back towards your 192.168.100.0/24 network?

Comment: No, it didn't ! I almost forgot to add the route back to 192.168.100./24, just added it and now everything works.

Thanks !